# Is there something like `help` or `dir` on the geth console?

Tags: go-ethereum

In python I can run `help(<function>)` to get some basic info or use `__doc__` to find out about what an object does. Is there something like that in the geth client?

Answer (score 3):

No help information unfortunately.

But type:

- "e" {TAB} {TAB} and you will get a listing of commands starting with "e"
- "et" {TAB} {TAB} and your command will be completed to "eth."
- "eth." {TAB} you will get a listing of the available functions from the "eth." space.

Same with "admin.", "debug.", "personal.", "web3.".

See the listing at https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/JavaScript-Console#management-api-reference for the commands that will work with this tab completion functionality.

You may also be interested in [What are the command line editing keys in geth's console](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6094/what-are-the-command-line-editing-keys-in-geths-console) for the list of editing keys, including this tab completion functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You might also find this list with the [JSON RPC methods](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC) helpful.